# How To Color Code Cells in Columns and Place in Body Email with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, colors, html-email

I have the below code. I wish to place a table in the body of an HTML email where I want negative values to be color-coded in red, positive values in green and unchanged values to display a dash. I can make it work for a single cell reference, however I can't figure out how to incorporate a For Each...Next command so that the code runs through an entire column and color codes all values accordingly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oEmail As Object


Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

rng = Range("A1")

If Range("A1") < 0 Then
rng = "<font color=""red"">" & "<b>" & rng & "</font>" & "</b>"
ElseIf Range("A1") > 0 Then
rng = "<font color=""green"">" & "<b>" & rng & "</font>" & "</b>"
Else: rng = "<b>" & "-" & "</b>"
End If


Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

oEmail.Close olSave
oEmail.Save
oEmail.BCC = ""
oEmail.Subject = "Test"
oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = """Hello"" <xxx@xxx>"
oEmail.HTMLBody = rng
oEmail.Display

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing

cleanup:
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the range to be from `A1` to the last used row?

Comment: @ Urdearboy - no in my case from A1 to A10 and from A12 to A17.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `For Each` loop like this:

---

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim myCell As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10", "A12:A17")

For Each myCell In rng
    If myCell < 0 Then
        myCell.[Format]
    ElseIf myCell > 0 Then
        myCell.[Format]
    Else
        myCell.[Format]
    End If
Next myCell
```

Comment: That works indeed and thanks for feedback, however it colour-codes the cell in Excel only. Once the range is placed in the body of an email, (using .HTMLBody) the colours disappear. This is why is used HTML commands in the If...Then section.

Comment: I didn't do any formatting - I just gave you the structure for your loop. You can use the format code you used. Instead of formatting `rng`, apply the format to `myCell`

Comment: Thanks with the help of your comments and some thinking myself i managed to solve the problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I used rng in the .HTMLBody section instead of RangetoHTML(rng) which had to be created as a function. Code is below.

```
Sub Test()
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oEmail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10, "A12:A17"")

For Each myCell In rng
If myCell < 0 Then
myCell.Font.Color = vbRed
ElseIf myCell > 0 Then
myCell.Font.Color = vbGreen
Else: myCell.Font.Color = vbBlack
End If
Next myCell

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

oEmail.BCC = ""
oEmail.Subject = "Test"
oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = """FBN Markets"" <xxx@xxx>"
oEmail.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
oEmail.Send

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing

cleanup:
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy 
h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center 
x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```